# What are some flutter/dart compatible databases that allow multiple inequality filters and are scalable as well?

Tags: sql, firebase, flutter, dart, nosql

I am a new developer and I started making projects with Flutter and Firebase. One of the projects that I am working on is heavily based on multiple inequality  (<, <=, >, >=, !=) comparisons. For example trying to find a barbershop where the Rating is higher than 4, More than x number of barbers are available, and the distance is less than y miles away and etc. Unfortunately, Even though I made my application using Firebase already, I am looking to change my database and I want to be able to filter out my data freely and not do it through my code because I have to pay for my document fetches.

I was wondering if there are any suggestions on Dart/Flutter Compatible Databases that have Firebase's Scalability and Affordability but also allow multiple inequality queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple inequality comparisons in firebase too. For example i used something like this in one of my projects.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: username)
        .where("name", isLessThan: username + 'z')
        .snapshots();
```

Comment: What I meant was on different fields. You are only using it on the "name" field.